# Driver problem with the tablet mode on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, tablet

i just want to suggest a thing here . I am using  Toshiba 
satellite 'E45W-C4200' and it came with pre-installd Windows 10. it is 
a touch screen ,and it has a tablet mode. When I switched to a 
tablet mode i.e.  flip the screen backwards, the keyboard and 
the touchpad used to be disabled automatically and ready to 
be used as a tablet.

I think this is because of the driver of the  magnet found under the keyboard that serve as a sensor when the screen is flipped. But after I entirely removed Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu the keyboard and the touchpad still are functional.

However they couldn't become disabled automatically like before in a tablet mode. To be frank this annoyed me a lot. Currently I use `xinput` to disable the keyboard and touchpad.

I hope this issue will be resolved when your next version of Ubuntu has been released.

Comment: I have the same issue in an HP Spectre x360 13-4105ns. What do you use in order to disable/enable them manually?